# what is the purpose of double implying?

Tags: c#

for example:

```
const decimal dollars = 25.50M;
```

why do we have to add that `M`?

why not just do:

```
const decimal dollars = 25.50;
```

since it already says `decimal`, doesnt it imply that `25.50` is a decimal?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

No.

`25.50` is a standalone expression of type `double`, not `decimal`.
The compiler will not see that you're trying to assign it to a `decimal` variable and interpret it as a decimal.

Except for lambda expressions, anonymous methods, and the conditional operator, all C# expressions have a fixed type that does not depend at all on context.

Imagine what would happen if the compiler did what you want it to, and you called `Math.Max(1, 2)`.
`Math.Max` has overloads that take `int`, `double`, and `decimal`.  Which one would it call?

Comment: @slaks:so what is the proper way of initiliazing a decimal?

Comment: They way you did, with an `M` suffix.

Comment: @jenny, just to get ahead of the next question, `double d = 1 / 2` equals 0. Think about why in the context of this question and answer.

Comment: What is this actually called?  Anyone have a link to the MSDN location that specifies all these?

Comment: Interesting tidbit according to VS 2010 IntelliSense (hover over number).  In `long x = 123;`, replacing 123 with different values... 0-2147483647 is `Int32`.  2147483648-4294967295 is `UInt32`.  4294967296-9223372036854775807 is `Int64`.  9223372036854775808-18446744073709551615 is `UInt64`.  -1 to -2147483648 is `Int32` (correctly detected extra negative value).  -2147483649 is `UInt32` ???.  -4294967296 to 9223372036854775808 is `Int64` (again correct).  -9223372036854775809 is `UInt64` ???  Seems like a minor bug to me.

Answer (score 10):

There are two important concepts to understand in this situation.

1. Literal Values
2. Implicit Conversion

Essentially what you are asking is whether a literal value can be implicitly converted between 2 types. The compiler will actually do this for you in some cases when there would be no loss in precision. Take this for example:

```
long n = 1000; // Assign an Int32 literal to an Int64.
```

This is possible because a `long` (Int64) contains a larger range of values compared to an `int` (Int32). For your specific example it is possible to lose precision. Here are the drastically different ranges for `decimal` and `double`.

```
Decimal: ±1.0 × 10−28 to ±7.9 × 1028
Double: ±5.0 × 10−324 to ±1.7 × 10308
```

With knowledge it becomes clear why an implicit conversion is a bad idea. Here is a list of implicit conversions that the C# compiler currently supports. I highly recommend you do a bit of light reading on the subject.

[Implicit Numeric Conversions Table](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y5b434w4.aspx)

Comment: A decimal can only go up to 8,121.2 ?! That's 7.9 x 1028. Wow, that's not much range. (My snide way of saying, I think you lost an "^" or a superscript in there.)

Comment: @Jay - I failed to come up with a clever retort to your snide remark so... shut up! :)

Answer (score 3):

Note also that due to the inner details of how doubles and decimals are defined, slight rounding errors can appear in your assignments or calculations.  You need to know about how floats, doubles, and decimals work at the bit level to always make the best choices.

For example, a double cannot precisely store the value 25.10, but a decimal can.

A double *can* precisely store the value 25.50 however, for fun binary-encoding reasons.

[Decimal structure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.decimal%28v=VS.80%29.aspx)

Comment: Ah yes, it is important to remember that there are two ways to loose numeric data. Magnitude and Precision.