# More on Implied Types

Tags: c#

As a follow up to the question [what is the purpose of double implying](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3866490/what-is-the-purpose-of-double-implying)...

Also, I read in an article a while back (no I don't remember the link) that it is inappropriate to do `decimal dollars = 0.00M;`. It stated that the appropriate way was `decimal dollars = 0;`. It also stated that this was appropriate for all numeric types. Is this incorrect, and why? If so, what is special about 0?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Well, for *any* integer it's okay to use an implicit conversion from `int` to `decimal`, so that's why it compiles. (Zero has some other funny properties... you can implicitly convert from any constant zero expression to any enum type. It *shouldn't* work with constant expressions of type `double`, `float` and `decimal`, but it happens to do so in the MS compiler.)

However, you *may* want to use `0.00m` if that's the precision you want to specify. Unlike `double` and `float`, `decimal` isn't normalized - so `0m`, `0.0m` and `0.00m` have different representations internally - you can see that when you call `ToString` on them. (The integer `0` will be implicitly converted to the same representation as `0m`.)

So the real question is, what do you want to represent in your particular case?